# Can't update the uibutton label

Tags: ios, uibutton, setneedsdisplay

I'm using the custom `MZFormSheetController` to use the custom "alert view". I have a button when I press it, it opens the `MZFormSheetController` and allows me to select a specific title for this button from `UIPickerView`. When I select the title from the picker, it is send to the `viewController` that contains the button by `setNeedsDisplay`

I want to change the title of the button with the selected title from the `pickerView`. I wrote the code but the title of the button doesn't updated..

In the button's `viewController`, The action of the button:

```
-(IBAction)openSelectCountries:(id)sender{
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"countriesPickerViewController"];

MZFormSheetController *formSheet = [[MZFormSheetController alloc] initWithViewController:vc];

formSheet.transitionStyle = MZFormSheetTransitionStyleSlideFromTop;
formSheet.shadowRadius = 2.0;
formSheet.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
formSheet.shouldDismissOnBackgroundViewTap = YES;
formSheet.shouldCenterVerticallyWhenKeyboardAppears = YES;

[formSheet presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIViewController *presentedFSViewController) {

}];

}
```

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// selectedCountryIndex2 is a static NSString

if (selectedCountryIndex != 0) {
    selectedCountryIndex2 = selectedCountryIndex;
 }
NSLog(@"selectedCountryIndex2: %d", selectedCountryIndex2);

if (selectedCountryIndex2 == 0) {
    NSLog(@"no country selected");
}else{
    NSLog(@"the selected country: %@", [countryArray objectAtIndex:selectedCountryIndex2]);

    [countrySelect setTitle:[countryArray objectAtIndex:selectedCountryIndex2] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

 }
```

in `CountriesPickerViewController.m`:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 return [countryArray count];
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return  [countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSLog(@"in pickerView: %@", [countryArray objectAtIndex:row]);

ContactUsViewController *contactUsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactUsViewController"];

contactUsViewController.selectedCountry = [countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
contactUsViewController.selectedCountryIndex = row;

[contactUsViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];

// to close the custom dialog
 UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"countriesPickerViewController"];

MZFormSheetController *formSheet = [[MZFormSheetController alloc] initWithViewController:vc];

[formSheet dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];

 }
```

The expected thing is that the `countrySelect` button change its title when `selectedCountryIndex2` is not equal 0 but this never happen although that the title is passed successfully and I got it by `NSLog`.

Comment: in your whole code there is no UIButton...

Comment: Which log you are getting? NSLog(@"the selected country..)??

Comment: @ Fahim Parkar.. it is the `countrySelect`

Comment: @Anil.. yes I added it, it is `NSLog(@"selectedCountryIndex2: %d", selectedCountryIndex2);`